# Square integrability of an absolute integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $h:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a complex-valued function. Also let$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|h(t)|dt<\infty$$Which is an improper Riemann integral. Is it true that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|h(t)|^2dt$$ also exists? I couldn't find a counterexample for that. Note that here I mean Riemann integral not Lebesgue integral. The main reason for asking that question is [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/70874/output-of-a-stable-lti-system/70875?noredirect=1#comment148085_70875) problem which asks "Does a stable LTI system with energy signal as input, always have energy signal as output?"

Comment: Take something like $h(t) = t^{-1/2}$ on $(0,1)$, $h(t)=0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Thanks. Is there any set of conditions which ensures square integrability for an absolute integrable function?